# How Trim Text In A Div Class Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone please let me know how to trim text like below using javascript only, not jQuery? This isn't working on mobile devices.

I have a function that calculates different dates over a period of time, but I need to trim the last 42 characters of the divs class="calculated" output.

The below works fine on desktop, but doesn't display the divs on mobile devices. I tested and removed the jQuery function and they show up, but I need them trimmed.

Thanks

```
(function ($) {
$('.calculated').text(function (_,txt) {
return txt.slice(0, -42);
});    
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) with [Element.innerHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to replace content of `div[class=calculated]`

```js
(function(event) { 
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('calculated')[0];
  alert(elem.innerHTML.slice(0, -42));
  elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.slice(0, -42);
})();
```

```html
<div class="calculated">Content longer that 42 chars.Content longer that 42 chars.Content longer that 42 chars.</div>
```

To **update all divs** with class `calculated` add `for loop` within result of document.getElementsByClassName, see code snippet below:

```js
(function() { 
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('calculated');
  for (var i=0;i < elements.length; ++i){

    elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.slice(0, -42);
  };
})();
```

```html
<div class="calculated">Content3 Content3 Content3 Content3 Content3 Content3 Content3 Content000 </div>

<div class="calculated">Content2 Content2 Content2 Content2 Content2 Content2 Content2 Content000  </div>

<div class="calculated">Content 1Content 1Content 1Content 1Content 1Content 1Content Content000</div>
```

**Good luck )**

Comment: Thanks for the response. This works, but only on the first div classed "calculated". I need it to apply to all divs classed with "calculated". Any thoughts there?

Comment: Yes. I need to trim all of them by 42 characters. Is this the job for a loop?

Comment: @billy_comic yes it is, i've updated answer to suit your needs.

Comment: Any idea why this would work on desktop browser but doesn't display anything on mobile?

Comment: @billy_comic try to remove main logic from wrapping into `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { }`

Answer (score 0):

```
function trimString(){
  return document.getElementsByClassName('calculated')[0].innerHTML.slice(0,-42);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function trimThingies() {
   var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('calculated');
   for (var i=0;i<targets.length;i++) {
      var tgt = targets[i];
      if (tgt.innerHTML.length > 42) {
        tgt.innerHTML = tgt.innerHTML.slice(0, -42);
      }
   }
}
```

Should do it. Then call trimThingies() on load or whenever appropriate.

Hardly elegant, but it should do the job.

Update: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/26qpfwpb/1/)

Comment: This is a rather destructive function, in the sense that calling it again would remove another 42 characters from those DIVs that had already been targeted, so I would probably consider trimming and holding the data outside the DOM structure - but that's out of scope of the question at hand I guess.

Comment: This works and serves the purpose, but for some reason, isn't trimming on mobile devices. In browser works great, but, from android, the divs populate empty.

Comment: the function assumed the length to always be more than 42 characters - if that's not the case, they would essentially end up empty, as everything that was in there would get trimmed. I've updated the answer to check the length before trimming.